# Efficient way to update the ArrayAdapter inside AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I am using XMLPullParser to parse XML feeds and then storing the incoming data in a List.
The issue is, I have multiple feeds to pull data from and a single list,

What I am doing is,

I created an Arraylist to store the data pulled from the XML,

```
protected ArrayList<String> feed_XMLs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Since I have multiple feeds, I stored them in an array

```
  public static String XML_URL[] = { "http://Feed1",
            "http://Feed2",
            "http://Feed3",
            };
```

and then I used PullParser inside AsyncTask to pull the data from each URL and create its object,

```
for (int x = 0; x < XML_URL.length; x++){
    GetXMLTitles xmlFirst = new GetXMLTitles(x);
    xmlFirst.execute();
}
```

I created a constructor inside AsyncTask class to select different URL on each iteration -> `new GetXMLTitles(x)`

On each iteration, a URL is selected and then title is pull and stored in the ArrayList `feed_XMLs`.

Later inside `onPostExecute` method of AsyncTask, this data is now pass to the ArrayAdapter,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, feed_XMLs);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Thats all.

The final output is a huge ArrayList `feed_XMLs` with hundred of titles.

On each iteration, new URL is selected and `feed_XMLs` ArrayList is updated and displayed on the Screen.

For example,

On first iteration, first URL is selected and all the titles are stored in `feed_XMLs`, `feed_XMLs` is changed. These titles are displayed on the screen.

On second iteration second URL is selected and all the titles are appended in `feed_XMLs`...and the process is continous for every iteration.

The problem is,

the scroll bar moves at the top of the screen on every iteration,

for example,

If I scroll all the way down and the ArrayAdapter is updated, I will automatically move all the way up on the screen, and this isn't what I want.

I want my screen to remain where it is when new data is updated in ArrayAdapter.

How can I achieve this ? Is it even possible ?

I have tried, `scrollview.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);` but that doesn't work either.

Is there anyway to update the ArrayAdapter in such a way that it has no effect in the scrolling ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you create a new Adapter in each **onPostExecute**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, feed_XMLs);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Just create the Adapter once and update it's data.

Something like this :

```
if(adapter!=null) {
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Edit:**

Thank you this solution works !

I created the `adapter` in main class like this,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

then in `onPostExecute`,

```
if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, feed_XMLs);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        else {
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: since the Adapter is created inside onPostExecute, wouldn't it automatically created on every iteration ? 
I cannot create ArrayAdapter inside main activity class because then the feed_XMLs data wouldn't have updated, I have to create ArrayAdapter inside Async onPostExecute, but how to create it just once ?

P.S: YOur solution isn't working

Comment: The solution works when you keep one instance of the adapter. Just keep a reference to the adapter on the main activity, create the adapter once(onPostExecute) , after that just update the adapter.